# Reduce memory usage in boost build

Tags: c++, linux, boost, g++, boost-build

I'm trying to build a C++ library on a linux system with constrained memory resources, using G++ 4.6. The library uses Boost heavily.

I've seen various threads here and in other websites regarding compilation speed, but I'm interested in tips and tricks to make G++ less demanding on memory resources, even though it means loosing speed.

EDIT: I've tried using precompiled headers for Boost, which improves only build speed, but still requires roughly the same amount of memory.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to build on an embedded platform. This is generally not a good idea. Instead use cross-compilation from a platform that's not constrained in the same way, and transfer the program to the platform after it's built.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible without changing this library implementation, in particular the way it uses `boost`. High memory usage at compile-time usually means that there are a lot of template instantiations.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No. We just have a very modest server a no resources to upgrade it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to play with the garbage collector settings.  The parameters are `ggc-min-expand` and `ggc-min-heapsize`. Also set your ulimit with `ulimit 65536` (or whatever) to reduce the heap size (RLIMIT_AS).

Lots of information on that in the [gcc manual here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

A good setting may be to set the ggc-min-expand param to 0 and ggc-min-heapsize param to 8192 and try with that...

CXXFLAGS="$(CXXFLAGS) --param ggc-min-expand=0 --param ggc-min-heapsize=8192"  or some such value.